# multiprocessing with Process library does not give results

Tags: python, multicore

I'd like to do multi-core processing on very long lists (not numpy arrrays!), but I can't get it to work. The examples I find do not help much either. My idea is to split that vector in several equal-sized parts, do something with the data, and return the modified data. The example operation is obviously simple; in reality it contains a number of if-statements and for-loops

```
ncore = 4
size = 100
vectors = []
for icore in range(ncore):
    vectors.append([vector[ind:ind+size] for ind in range(icore * size, (icore + 1) * size)])
```

and the functions

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def some_func(vector):
    return [val*val for val in vector]

if True:
    
    for vector in vectors:
        # print(name)
        proc = Process(target=some_func, args=(vector,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

But there is no output.

Solutions?

thanks, Andreas

Comment: Are you doing numpy stuff?  If so, you may be able to use multithreading, which avoids the overhead of launching and initializing a new process.

Comment: **multiprocessing does not share state**. It creates seperate Python processes.

Comment: @Time: Nope, it's not numpy stuff, it's a regular list with text that needs to be processed.

Comment: @ Juan: sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Whether or not it generates separate processes is not that important (to me), I just want a single processed list as result